# How to create a dataframe with repeated columns created from randomly sampling another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, random

I am trying to repeatedly add columns to a dataframe using random sampling from another dataframe.

My first dataframe with the actual data to be sampled from looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(cat = c("a", "b", "c","a", "b", "c"),
                 x = c(6,23,675,1,78,543))
```

I have another dataframe like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(obs =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  cat=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c","c","c", "c"))
```

I want to add 1000 new columns to df2 that randomly samples from df, grouped by cat. I figure out a (probably very amateurish) way of doing this once, by using slice_sample() to make a new dataframe sample1 with a random sample of df, and then merging sample1 with df2.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(cat)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(cat)

sample1 <- slice_sample(df, preserve = T, n=3, replace = T )
sample1 <- sample1 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(obs=c(1:9)) %>%
  select(-cat)

df3 <- merge(df2,sample1, by= "obs")
```

Now, I want to find a way to repeat this 1000 times, to end up with df3 with 1000 columns (x1,x2,x3 etc.)

I have looked into repeat loops, but haven't been able to figure out how to make the above code work inside the loop.

Comment: I think you can wrap this in a function and use `replicate(1000, call_your_fn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option that might help

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
n <- 1000
res <- cbind(
  dt2[, .(obs)],
  dt2[
    ,
    replicate(n, sample(dt[.BY, x, on = "cat"], .N, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE),
    cat
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create a function and then use either `replicate` or `rerun` (from `purrr`) before doing the join

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(dat1) {
            dat1 %>%
                 group_by(cat) %>%
                 slice_sample(n = 3, replace = TRUE)  %>%
                     ungroup() %>%
                     mutate(obs = row_number()) %>%
                     select(-cat) 
         
      
      
      }
    
n <- 10
out <- rerun(10, f1(df)) %>% 
         c(list(df2), .) %>% 
         reduce(inner_join, by = 'obs') %>%  
          rename_at(vars(starts_with('x')), ~ str_c('x', seq_along(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep only 3 X number of unique `cat` value rows in `df2`. Use `replicate` to repeat the sampling process `n` times and add `n` new columns.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 10
df2 <- df2 %>% slice(1:(3*n_distinct(cat)))

df2[paste0('x', 1:n)] <- replicate(n, df %>%
                                       group_by(cat) %>%
                                       slice_sample(n = 3, replace = TRUE) %>%
                                       pull(x))

#  obs cat  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10
#1   1   a   6   1   1   6   6   1   1   1   6   6
#2   2   a   6   1   1   1   1   6   1   1   1   1
#3   3   a   1   6   1   6   1   6   6   1   6   6
#4   4   b  78  78  78  23  78  78  78  78  23  23
#5   5   b  78  78  78  23  23  23  78  78  78  23
#6   6   b  78  78  23  78  78  78  23  23  78  23
#7   7   c 675 543 543 543 543 543 675 543 543 675
#8   8   c 543 543 675 675 675 675 675 543 675 543
#9   9   c 543 543 675 543 675 543 675 675 543 675
```